# How do i use one to many relationship within Laravel 8 Middleware?

Tags: php, laravel, inertiajs

I have a `Users` and `Roles` table in my database. One `user` can have many `roles`. I am using Laravel 8, I want to be able to return all `roles` for that `user` within the middleware (I am using inertia.js - `handleinertiarequest.php`).

#### Roles Table:

| id | role | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | super_admin | 3 |
| 2 | admin | 3 |
| 3 | user | 3 |

#### Users Table:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Some name |
| 2 | Some other name |
| 3 | Joe Bloggs |

#### User Model (`User.php`):

```php
public function userroles()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Roles::class);
}
```

#### Roles Model (`Roles.php`):

```php
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

#### `HandleInertiaRequest.php`:

```php
public function share(Request $request)
{
    return array_merge(parent::share($request), [
        'auth' => function () use ($request) {
            return [
                'user' => $request->user() ? [
                    'id' => $request->user()->reference,
                    'first_name' => $request->user()->first_name,
                    'last_name' => $request->user()->last_name,
                    'role_staff' => \App\Models\Roles::select('id'),
                ] : null,
            ];
        },
    ]);
}
```

#### `Layout.vue`:

```html
{{ $page.props.auth.user.role_staff }}
```

So if I am logged in as `Joe Bloggs` (`id = 3`), I want it to return `3 roles` (or even just 1, if using the `id`). But this doesn't return anything or show any errors. What am i missing here? Thanks

Comment: To get the current user roles using the relation `userroles()` do `$request->user()->userroles`. I suggest that you change the method name to just `roles()`

Comment: thanks @N69S, im getting the error: Unknown column 'roles.deleted_at' in 'where clause'. im just selecting the id, so not sure why it's asking for deleted_at. return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'id')->select('id'); is this to do with use SoftDeletes? any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: remove the `select('id')` from the relation. what are you trying to do ? with the line i gave you, you get all the user roles.

Answer (score 0):

Use this relationship method in user modal:

```
public function userRoles()
{
    $this->hasMany('App\Models\role_table_modal_name','user_id');
}
```

Then in controller/middleware call your User modal:

```
$ user_roles = User::find($id)->with('userRoles')->get();
```